Why do I keep on receiving ENOBUFS errors in my nfqueue program even when my buffer is big enough?
I'm writing a simple network packet mangler in C++ which only changes the TTL value (for now). The main loop is receiving requests from the netfilter queue using recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) and then processes those requests using nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv). The buffer size is 500000000 bytes, which is about 500 megabytes or 4000 megabits. The internet speed is nowhere close to 4 gigabits (and even if it would be 4 gigabits, I'm not transferring that much data), yet the recv function keeps on receiving the ENOBUFS ("No buffer space available" when formatted using strerror) when I, for example, run a speed test on speed.cloudflare.com. I don't understand how I'm running out of buffer space here. The code that receives the requests is:
// created before in the code: char buf[500000000] = {0};
fd = nfq_fd(h);
while (true) {
    rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (rv < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error in recv: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    } else nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
}

The code that processes the packets is also very simple, I don't think the reason behind the "No buffer space left" error is slow processing of packets. As I said before, it just changes the TTL (time-to-live) value.
static int cb(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg, struct nfq_data *nfa, void *_data) {
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;
    ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
    if (!ph) {
        data->packetsRejected += 1;
        return -1;
    }
    int id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);
    unsigned char* packetData;
    int length = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &packetData);
    if (length == -1) {
        int result = nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_DROP, 0, NULL);
        data->packetsRejected += 1;
        return result;
    }
    uint8_t ipVersion = (packetData[0] & 0b11110000) >> 4;
    if (ipVersion == 4) {
        uint8_t headerLength = packetData[0] & 0b1111;
        if (headerLength < 5 || headerLength > 15) {
            int result = nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
            data->packetsRejected += 1;
            data->bytesRejected += length;
            return result;
        }
        headerLength *= 4;
        packetData[8] = 64;
        fixIPv4Checksum(packetData, headerLength);
    }
    int result = nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, length, packetData);
    data->packetsAccepted += 1;
    data->bytesAccepted += length;
    return result;
}


could be system limits , how much has been sent/received before you start getting the problem

@ticktalk I ran a speedtest on speed.cloudflare.com, the speed is 30-40 Mbps (with and without the network filter) and it says it can consume up to 200 MB of data (total, not per second).

Don't you use libmnl?  Besides, recv() may return -1 and errno is set to ENOBUFS in case that your application is not fast enough to retrieve the packets from the kernel. In that case, you can increase the socket buffer size by means of nfnl_rcvbufsiz().  Check the size by sysctl -a | grep rmem_

@Ale I use https://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html, packets are sent to the netfilter queue using iptables. I'll try nfnl_rcvbufsiz and some other functions I found in the library header file when searching that function now

@Ale changing the nfnl_rcvbufsiz (nfnl_rcvbufsiz(h->nfnlh, 500000000)) and the max length (nfq_set_queue_maxlen(qh, 500000000)) to a relatively big number worked.
